# Post thumbnail not displaying correct size

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I created a custom template. It contains 3 columns, and the middle column should only display the post thumbnail. But no matter what size attribute I'm setting, it's not changing the size the way I want. I'd like the image to take over most of the space from that column.

```
    <div class="col-lg-4">
       .. first column with some content
    </div><!-- col-lg-4 -->

     <div class="col-lg-4"> 
       <?php
        //post_thumbnail
        if (!empty(get_the_post_thumbnail())) : ?>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(360,466), array( 'class' => 'aligncenter'));
        endif; ?>

     </div><!-- col-lg-4 -->
     <div class="col-lg-4">
         third column with some content..
    </div><!-- col-lg-4 -->
```

No matter what I put as a size (i also tried 'medium', 'full' etc.) it's remaining the same size as in the picture below:
[image]

any ideas where my problem is?

**EDIT**

the same thing happens when I simply add

```
if (!empty(get_the_post_thumbnail())) : ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();
            endif; ?>
```

or add any size (thumbnail, middle, large). It doesn't change anything..

Comment: have a look at CSS if there are rules that constrain img size

Comment: what do you mean? which css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit css?

```
img{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: but that would edit all the images not only that one specific page

Comment: You must name the class differently for the images on this page.

Comment: @Quang please update the answer with proper code and a bit explanation, like why would it solve the problem? Otherwise this looks like a low quality answer.

Comment: @Fayaz okay you win 

Comment: LOL, it's not about me, they system is considering it as a low quality answer & I'm getting it from the review queue. Besides, not everyone knows exactly where a problem comes from, so a bit of explanation with code always helps.

Comment: @Quang this would edit all of my images, I'd only like to customize that specific page..
no matter what I put as a size, it never changes anything..

Comment: @sonja I will give you an example, for example, the product page, you should set the class name for the image attribute as below.
`.product-page-image{
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: @Quang I know but no matter what I add to the css file, it doesn't change the image size on that page..
I just added a new class "cover-image" and applied the width and height in my css class but nothing happens..

Comment: @sonja You can give me your link to that page :)

Comment: @Quang I eventually got it to work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After you added `add_image_size( 'book-image', 360, 466, true );` try calling the_post_thumbnail like that: also reganrate the thumbnails

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'book-image' );
```

Comment: the 360,466 where just numbers to play with the size. I'd actually want the size to be responsive to the screen. so it's more a 100% according to the column size

Comment: any other ideas how it might work?